# i am unable to handle a error, which pops up as soon as i use variable "n" with newline character i.e "\n" in print statement

Tags: c, error-handling

i am facing an unknown error when i use variable "n" with newline character i.e "\n" in print statement in visual studio code

```
int main(){
    int n;
    printf("enter the number n\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int sum=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=10;i++){
        int prod=i*n;
        sum=sum+prod;
    }
    printf("sum of multiplication table is %d",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

i am receiving an error which is as follows:

```
Program 'sum.exe' failed to run: Unknown error (0xfffffffe)At line:1 char:120
+ ...  tutorial course\" ; if ($?) { gcc sum.c -o sum } ; if ($?) { .\sum }
+                                                                   ~~~~~.
At line:1 char:120
+ ...  tutorial course\" ; if ($?) { gcc sum.c -o sum } ; if ($?) { .\sum }
+                                                                   ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

i am unable to understand how to handle this problem, please help me to tackle this problem

I tried to write variable "n" with newline character "\n", but it showed me unknown error, I was expecting to get the desired output of my code  that is sum of multiplication table

Comment: What tutorial course are you following? What compiler are you using?

Comment: If the program failed to run, it might not exist. That would happen if the compiler aborts due to errors. Check the compiler error messages. You are missing an include. Add the line `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of your program.

Comment: Please try running `./sum.exe` from the powershell command prompt, also `$?`, replace with `$LASTEXITCODE` and check if its 0, sounds like you're checking the compilation for errors, if it builds an executable, the error code be 0 and run it, that correct?

Comment: Assuming the above is your complete program, you need to add `#include <stdio.h>` as the first line. Otherwise the compiler won't know about print or scanf.